Unable to catchup for more than 2-3 days with non-voting account-index extended RPC
I try to setup my non-voting account-index extended RPC and it can't catch up for more than 2-3 days.
I'm using AWS x2idn.16xlarge which means: 1TB RAM, 64 vCPU, 3 * 1900GBNVMe SSD, 50Gbps network bandwidth
After I have got the latest incremental snapshot I have added  --no-snapshot-fetch as well, but still can't catch up and the average slot / s is around -1.2.. :/
any ideas?
Solana validator config:
exec solana-validator \
    --identity validator-keypair.json \
    --vote-account vote-account-keypair.json \
    --log /home/sol/solana-validator.log \
    --ledger /mnt/ledger \
    --accounts /mnt/accounts \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --gossip-port 8801 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --no-voting \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --limit-ledger-size 50000000 \
    --account-index program-id \
    --account-index spl-token-owner \
    --account-index spl-token-mint \
    --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
    --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
    --enable-cpi-and-log-storage \
    --known-validator BFquPCAYdjN9QyLVfuGrQdJTF9Ct7Z85FDxhFeLcpFqR \
    --known-validator eoKpUABi59aT4rR9HGS3LcMecfut9x7zJyodWWP43YQ \
    --known-validator 5D1fNXzvv5NjV1ysLjirC4WY92RNsVH18vjmcszZd8on \
    --known-validator td2GGWDsCJ6LvjN89oLJvmrDwE14neNrbqQ9s3tVkPy \
    --known-validator RBFiUqjYuy4mupzZaU96ctXJBy23sRBRsL3KivDAsFM \
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --wait-for-supermajority 246464040 \
    --expected-shred-version 50093 \
    --expected-bank-hash 2QEvYhBgeWPJbC84fMTTK9NgntqiUAWiBEBf21rtTmng

